# ag-grid-v19 defaultToolPanel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I am creating a sideBar config object like this:

```
{    
sideBar: {
        toolPanels: [
            {
                id: 'columns',
                labelDefault: 'Columns',
                labelKey: 'columns',
                iconKey: 'columns',
                toolPanel: 'agColumnsToolPanel',
                toolPanelParams: {
                    suppressValues: true,
                    suppressPivots: true,
                    suppressPivotMode: true,
                    suppressRowGroups: false
                }
            },
            {
                id: 'filters',
                labelDefault: 'Filters',
                labelKey: 'filters',
                iconKey: 'filter',
                toolPanel: 'agFiltersToolPanel',
            }
        ],
        defaultToolPanel: ''
    }
}
```

When the grid loads up, I see these warnings in the console:

> "ag-grid: can't set the visibility of the tool panel item [] since it can't be found

My intent is to initially suppress the toolPanel.  The docs say to set the defaultToolPanel to none to accomplish this; however, I get the above warnings every time.  Am I missing something?  Is there a more correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: The warning looks like a bug, in this case. Ignore it for now, and report an issue: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues

Comment: Will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opened an issue for this potential bug.
https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2627